# Gem for push notifications for Android and iOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, push-notification

I am working on a project in Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3 and I am looking for a gem to send push notifications to my iOS app and to my Android app.

I have found one for iOS  [jtv-apns gem](https://github.com/justintv/APNS) but as I have asked in this question, I haven't been able to make it work and I haven't received any answers yet. 
I have also found [apn_on_rails](https://github.com/jwang/apn_on_rails) but as the instructions are not for rails 3, I don't know if it is compatible.

For android, all I have found is [c2dm_on_rails](https://github.com/pimeys/c2dm_on_rails) so far, but only works with ruby 1.8 and rails 2.

As suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206050/rails-push-for-iphone-and-android), [Urban ship](http://urbanairship.com/) is not an option for me right now. I would like to implement it myself or find a gem to help me do that.

Do you know any gem I can use for ruby 1.9 and rails 3 or a good tutorial I can follow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using [apn_on_rails](https://github.com/natescherer/apn_on_rails) the rails 3 branch. You can find a really good tutorial [here](http://yekmer.posterous.com/how-to-send-iphone-push-notifications-in-rail)

And for android I used [speed_c2dm](https://github.com/sghael/speedy_c2dm)

Comment: Still the best ones to use, a few years later?  Sadly the tutorial is gone now that posterous is down.

Comment: This is 3 years old, we need something better. the only thing i found is prowl with the iOS prowl app but i don't like it that much although it seems to work.

Answer (score -1):

Use Prowl iOS client and 
prowler gem

http://www.prowlapp.com

If someone knows a better solution that is up2date please post as comment!