# Upload Information to Rails and update Android application

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails

So I have an Android application that visualizes points of interest with relevant information. I also plan to have a Ruby on Rails application, that allows users to upload new points of interests with the appropriate attributes (i.e. information). What would be the best way to update my Android application's SQLite database to reflect the new information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you updating your RoR application, you want to reflect the changes on your android application as well?? hmm, if in case, you can use GCM which will give u real time push msg http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

here is a post about it also.
[Gem for push notifications for Android and iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107583/gem-for-push-notifications-for-android-and-ios)

correct me if im missunderstanding your question

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising!